# Python 2.7 to 3.5 unzip error

Tags: python, python-3.x, unzip, zip

I am trying to update a script from 2.7 to 3.5. I keep getting an error with the following:

```
def _openScure(self, new_image):
    return os.system("unzip " + new_image)
```

The issue is with unzip in python 3.5 what should I replace it with?

The error says:

```
'unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

I have tried the following:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("name.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref . extractall (".")
```

Running win7 python 3.5.

Here is a link to the entire script I am trying to update to 3.5. The issue I am having is with line 17. Any thoughts?

https://github.com/agusmakmun/Some-Examples-of-Simple-Python-Script/blob/master/Stegano-Extract-and-Read-File-From-Image/script.py

Comment: What happened when you tried the below?

Comment: If the code in the first snippet quit work with that error, it sounds like the `unzip` command—which is independent of the version of Python that's being used—which used to be installed (or was in the same directory as the script) isn't there anymore. Are you using the same computer?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys, so an hour of playing later and i have the following.
def _openScure(self, new_image):
          return os.system(("with zipfile.ZipFile(""+new_image", "r") as zip_ref:
   zip_ref . extractall (".") )

and now SyntaxError on the "as".

so my understanding is unzip command is not  compatible on 3.5 as martineau says. Using a different computer totally i didnt write the original script just trying to make it work on 3.5 which i have had a lot of success until this hurdle.

Comment: Either install unzip on your system, or use the Python package to do the unzipping.